# Google Maps API - Markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to add markers to a map on my page using Google's Javascript API. I know how to do this simply, just with little marker images in various spots on the map, however, I want this to be a little bit cooler.

I want to place transparent circles (tiny ones), on the map in place of markers, but make it so when they are crowded in one area, they layer on top of each other (obviously), and create a darkening effect, so you can kind of see where things are more crowded at a high level, not just a crazy amount of the same exact image marker (which would look really sloppy and weird).

Have any of you done anything like this before, or should I be approaching this differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like a heat map?

http://code.google.com/p/gheat/ or http://www.heatmapapi.com/

Comment: That's exactly it! Thank you!

Comment: I don't need this right now, but have a project that can really benefit from your answer in near future. I just didn't know the term 'heat map', so you save me a lot  of time. Definitely +1.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on that page :
http://florent.clairambault.fr/add-a-circle-overlay-to-google-maps-api-v3

I think this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

try making it a shadow. Shadows layer on top of each other like your described. Example:

```
var shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('/images/pin_shadow.png',
    new google.maps.Size(27,30),
    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    new google.maps.Point(0, 19));

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    shadow: shadow,
    (otherproperties here),
});
```

Let me know if this works.

Kevin